# Spring boot 2 with embedded postgres - At least one JPA metamodel must be present

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, configuration, spring-data-jpa

The application is a Spring boot v2 application containing the following dependencies:

```
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
        <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.opentable.components</groupId>
        <artifactId>otj-pg-embedded</artifactId>
        <version>0.12.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
        <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
        <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.7.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

and `application.yml` contains the configuration for an actual postgres instance, and I've made a single entity

```
package org.myorg.project.domain;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "SomeEntity")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class SomeEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "someValue")
    private String someValue;
}
```

and a repository

```
package org.myorg.project.repository;

import org.myorg.project.domain.SomeEntity;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface SomeEntityRepository extends JpaRepository<SomeEntity, Long> {
}
```

Running the application and using the repository and entity works as expected. Database connection is made and entities are persisted, all is well.

Tests... not so much. I want to setup tests to use the [OpenTable Embedded PostgreSQL Component](https://github.com/opentable/otj-pg-embedded) so that tests use the same db implementation to avoid headaches and also to be able to test stored procedures and things in-memory db's usually don't provide. I've written a simple test with configuration:

```
package org.myorg.project.repository;

import com.opentable.db.postgres.junit.EmbeddedPostgresRules;
import com.opentable.db.postgres.junit.SingleInstancePostgresRule;
import org.myorg.project.domain.SomeEntity;
import org.junit.ClassRule;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.test.context.support.AnnotationConfigContextLoader;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
//@ContextConfiguration(classes = {SomeEntityRepositoryTest.Config.class})
//@ContextConfiguration(loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class SomeEntityRepositoryTest {

    @ClassRule
    public static SingleInstancePostgresRule singleInstancePostgresRule = EmbeddedPostgresRules.singleInstance();

    @Autowired
    private SomeEntityRepository someEntityRepository;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        System.out.println(singleInstancePostgresRule);
        System.out.println(singleInstancePostgresRule.getEmbeddedPostgres());

        System.out.println(someEntityRepository);
    }

    @Configuration
    @EntityScan(basePackageClasses = SomeEntity.class)
    @EnableJpaRepositories(basePackageClasses = SomeEntityRepository.class)
    public static class Config {

        @Bean
        public DataSource dataSource() {
            return singleInstancePostgresRule.getEmbeddedPostgres().getPostgresDatabase();
        }
    }
}
```

However upon running this test I get an `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: At least one JPA metamodel must be present!` exception.

As you can see I have both `@EnableJpaRepositories` and `@EntityScan` annotations with configured base package paths. I've tried both the string variant and the class variant but the result is the same.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: any updates on this? I want to do the same thing